# Close information accuracy

Tags: discussion, support, vote-to-close, dupehammer

I am relatively new to the SQL gold badge, so not sure if this may be confusing for others too.

Because of the gold badge I closed this question without more votes: [How to get second, third and more values from string with fields separated by commas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43813292/how-to-get-second-and-third-and-so-on-values-saperate-after-comma-in-sql)

At first I edited the question to try to understand what was happening. Then when I found a similar question and closed it I saw someone had already voted to close as unclear what it was asking.

[image]

Now on the banner it looks like `marc_s` agreed with my duplicate decision when it wasn't that way.

I know it probably isn't big deal. I don't mind sharing the credit. My worry is that in the case I made a wrong choice on the duplicated answer Marc unknowingly will also appear to have made the wrong choice.

Comment: This isn't specific to the dup hammer; this is just how closing has always worked; all of the voters are shown and only one reason is shown, even if some of the voters used a different reason.

Comment: I find it annoying, but it hasn't yet caused me any problems.

Comment: I often leave a comment with the reason I chose and why when I'm listed under the closers for a reason I disagree with, or when it is apparent that I will be. There are many feature requests here and on M.SE to separate out the close votes and such.

Comment: What Servy wrote. Also note that some close votes (in the "off-topic" section if I remember correctly) also list who voted for exactly that what is shown there. Like here: [What is the Java equivalent for LINQ?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1217228) (just a randomly picked question)